How do I fix Google Chrome error code 159 using 22.04
My Google Chrome browser gives the error code 159 when ever I open the browser and every time I click on any url it still only gives the error 159. When I input "sudo google-chrome -version" I get 90.0.4430.93. when I google "latest google-chrome -version" I get 131.0.6738.0. How do I get the latest version and will it also fail? Selecting an incognito page also returns 159.   I did find ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT (-159) in the Chrome list of errors.

Why would you run sudo google-chrome -version ?  as the sudo would imply to me you may have made a permissions change to your file-system that has created problems (google-chrome is a user app which shouldn't be run with sudo)
